# What exactly happens at the snap?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

When Hulk snaps the Infinity Gauntlet in *Avengers: Endgame*, what exactly does happen?

Do the missing people just return or does the snap set time back to five years prior?

I was confused because if it just returns the missing people, why does no one seem to age? When Peter Parker returns to school, everyone is still the same age as he was but theoretically, they should be 5 years older.

My conclusion is that the new Spider-Man movie has to be set before *Avengers: Infinity War*, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was answered by Peter himself in the film:

> **Peter:** Do you remember when we were in space? And I got all dusty? I must've passed out, 'cause I woke up, and you were gone.
>
> **Peter:** But Doctor Strange was there, right? He was like, "It's been five years. Come on, they need us!"

And also answered by [AJ](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99812/1190) in a similar post:

> As Director Joe Russo [explains](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-spider-man-movie-timeline-peter-age-far-from-home/),
>
> > As for Peter Parker and those who got dusted, they were basically taking a nap in which no one ages. "**To those dusted people, they had no conscious in these past 5 years**," Joe Russo went on. "**They didn't know what happened. It's as if they had just woke up from a long sleep.** The only one who was aware about how many years has passed was Doctor Strange, because he has already seen that when he was time mediating on Titan.

Also from [bgr](https://bgr.com/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-ending-russo-brothers-on-captain-america-iron-man/):

> Q: What about those people who got dusted? What did those five years mean to them? Why didn't they grow older when undusted?
>
> A: Yes, those people whom was lucky to survive the snap are 5 years older than the people who just got back. The reason Spider Man saw his friend again in high school at the end was simply because his friends was unfortunately also dusted like Spider Man was. Of course, there are people in his grade whom didn't die and they are probably already in colleges by now. To those dusted people, they had no conscious in these past 5 years. They didn't know what happened. It's as if they had just woke up from a long sleep. The only one who was aware about how many years has passed was Doctor Strange, because he has already seen that when he was time mediating on Titan. Parker's reunion with Ned was a touching moment. There are also people whom indeed moved on but suddenly was reunited with their lost ones. Yeah it's kind a complicated world now.

Answer (score 9):

> I was confused because if it just returns the missing people, why does no one seem to age? When Peter Parker returns to school, everyone is still the same age as he was but theoretically, they should be 5 years older.

The people who were *snapped* were just brought back (to the 5 years later) and the rest of the population lived out those 5 years.

Granted there appears to be some discrepancy between the ages but we don't know who was snapped and who wasn't in the montage so it's possible that the ones we *do* see were also snapped.

Comment: Its interesting because from the perspective of age related milestones, like age to vote, age eligible to become President, etc, there will be two different classes of aged people... For example, Peter Parker's classmates that survive the snap are 18 and PP himself is 18D, where the D indicates Dusted or "The Vanished/Devanished" and cant use the age from their birth certificate

Answer (score 3):

The living creatures are brought back into the present, time isn't reset and those that survived aren't reset to five years ago. We know this because this is what they tried to do as it is what Tony asked them to do. We also know the ones who survived are still 5 years older as Cassie hasn't gone younger again. We also know those that were brought back seem to be the same age as we see with Peter who is still in school and comments something along the lines of one moment he was being erased and the next he was back.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Parker felt like no time at all had passed, so presumably the snapped people didn't age.

Comment: Hi there. The first line is part of an answer, but about the second, you should rather ask it as a new one as it's not an answer - see [ask] and the [help] for more guidance on how to do that. :)