# The People's Ages in Avengers: Endgame

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, we see that Professor Hulk wields the Stark gauntlet and unsnaps the dusted people.

This act is basically at the 5 years in the future mark, so are all the unsnapped people basically 5 years younger than all their peers

For example, Spiderman is part of it, so is Peter Parker now 5 years younger than Ned/classmates, etc?

Comment: Related, unsure if dupe because I'm not sure what you're asking: [What exactly happens at the snap?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99666/63559) - the answer addresses the age thing.