# Did people feel pain when they died in Infinity War?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Simple question, did those of the population who were considered in the half that needed to die via Thanos and his infinity gauntlet, feel pain when they were melting away?

### Did they feel pain when dying?

Comment: I don't see why this is getting down-voted, even if the answer is an educated guess, it's not completely opinion. "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience"

Comment: @Bee I assume there's downvoting because the answer seems self-evident on watching the film.  Various characters are seen as the snap, none of them are visibly in pain.  Shocked and confused, yes, but not obviously in pain.

Comment: @Snow, I see where you're coming from but I don't think that's a fair to downvote, just because it may seem obvious to some people!

Answer (score 14):

## Probably not.

**Disclaimer: This answer contains educated guesses and speculation.**

> **Dr. Strange:** [You want] to murder trillions.
>
> **Thanos:** With all six stones, I could simply snap my fingers, and they would all cease to exist. I call that... mercy.

It's not flat out said that the process is painless, but Thanos reassures Dr. Strange that the process is "merciful" when the latter refers to it as murder.

Additionally, no one aside from Spider-Man displays any reaction of panic or agony as they disintegrate-- only looks of shock, bewilderment, and confusion, and occasionally a quiet and solemn expression of sorrow (such as Star-Lord's "Aw, man")

> **Mantis:** Something… is… happening.

> **Spider-Man:** Mr. Stark? I don’t feel so good…

The only counterexamples we have of individuals feeling the Snap happening in any way are **Mantis** and **Spider-Man**, both of whom possess some form of extrasensory perception.

- Mantis, an empath, is able to feel that something is about to happen to those around her, though she is apparently uncertain what. Nevertheless, she too disintegrates without any apparent pain.
- Spider-Man's <s>"Peter tingle"</s> Spider-Sense (though it has not been called by this name in the MCU thus far), which warns him of oncoming danger, could be what gave him such a terrible and panic-inducing feeling.

Comment: Adding something, I think Spidey's resilience allowed him to hang on for few more seconds. not the spider-sense. Also, we see his spider sense (kind of), slightly before the first attack on earth happening, when he was in the school bus

Comment: Would probably have upvoted anyway, but the crossed out peter tingle made it for me

Comment: @Vishwa I don't mean to imply that Spider-Sense made Peter take longer to dust, just that the sense of impending danger is what made him "not feel so good". And I don't think he took longer because of his enhanced physiology, either; it doesn't make sense to "heal" from "ceasing to exist", and his suit dusts slowly just like the rest of him. I think it was simply a dramatic choice on the part of the filmmakers; some other characters like Fury also appear to dust more slowly, while some like Bucky and T'Challa (both of whom have enhanced physiology too) appear to dust quicker than most others.

Comment: We also see the blip's effects in far from home and there are those that were still playing music, this suggests no pain was felt or it would have effected the players ability to perform...

Comment: this is a very good answer

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

If we take a look at the people who were vanished didn't feel pain, but they were bewildered by seeing others getting disappeared and then seeing the world vanish before their eyes.

They felt weird, but not the pain.

As per my [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/99812/27264) to another question, they felt like they were passed out, which indicate that they didn't feel pain.

Spiderman is scared not feeling pain. He can sense that something is about to happen.

Comment: Adding to this, the two who do show something like pain are Mantis and Spider-man, but what they may actually be showing is fear. Mantis is an empath and can sense the collective fear of the universe and Peter can sense that something is happening. Hence Peter's reaction, which is more fear than pain.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, they did not feel any pain. We can see this from the perspective of several characters who experienced it and came back in the aftermath of *Avengers: Endgame*.

For instance, Yelena Belova was dusted and undusted in a matter of seconds (from her point of view), as we witness in *Hawkeye* season 1, episode 5. She did not seem to suffer any physical distress during or after the event.

Similarly, Monica Rambeau was snapped while she was asleep in her mother’s hospital room, and woke up five years later, as shown in *WandaVision* season 1, episode 4. She was confused and shocked, but not in pain. Many others were also restored during the event, and none of them seemed to be in pain, except for the one person that Monica ran into, but that was due to the collision.

We also see many people who were blipped back into existence in *Spider-Man: Far From Home*. They appeared to be fine, except for some minor inconveniences and collisions with other people or objects.

Answer (score 0):

## It's unclear

Certainly there are *indications* that some characters feel *something* but whether this is actual PAIN or merely a feeling of disintegration / railing against death isn't clear.

Peter Parker seems to know something is wrong...also Drax but others just "dust" without comment or screams.

Indeed, when Peter Parker **returns** he relates it to like being asleep and then being woken up by Dr Strange. This would indicate that actual PAIN wasn't involved.